# Sorting a multi-datatype String

Tags: java, sorting

Is there a way to sort a single String containing multiple data types?

example:
    //a string containing int and words(strings)
    String str1 = "1 one 2 two t";
    String str2 = "1 two 3 two t";
    String str3 = "1 three 1 two t";

let's say I wanted to sort it JUST by the 2nd int within those three strings.

Is there a way to tell java to search a just particular part of a String?

so the output that I want would be be list like:

```
str3
str1
str2

or 

"1 three 1 two t"
"1 two 2 two t"
"1 one 3 two t"
```

Comment: implements your own comparator

Comment: @Alex I have tried that however, I don't see how it is useful in this case. let me edit my question and elaborate on it a bit more

Comment: so see the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by sorting a single `String`?  You should split out the string into whatever groupings you want to sort on, and then sort that.  If your data has a particular format, you should write a short, simple `class` containing the elements split out into appropriate fields.

Answer (score 0):

Until you edit your question, I assume that you have a list of Strings like the one defined in your question.

In that case you can do like this with your own Comparator, no error checking but you see the idea:

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
     public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         String[] parts1 = s1.split(" ");
         String[] parts2 = s2.split(" ");
         Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(parts1[2]);
         Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(parts2[2]);
         return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
Collections.sort(Arrays.asList("3 three 4 four", "1 one 2 two", "5 five 6 six"), new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own comparator that compares strings as you need.  Something like this:

```
String [] values = new String [] {"foo 7 bar 3 foobar", "why 2 by 2 is 4?"};
Arrays.sort (values, new Comparator <String> ()
{
    @Override
    public int compare (String o1, String o2)
    {
        return extract2ndInt (o1).compareTo (extract2ndInt (o2));
    }

    private Integer extract2ndInt (String s)
    {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile ("\\d+").matcher (s);
        m.find ();
        m.find ();
        return Integer.parseInt (m.group ());
    }
});
System.out.println (values [0]);
System.out.println (values [1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways of doing this.

### The Proper Way

Step one - stop using a String.  By your own admission, this string "contains multiple variable types".  That's not a string, it's a class (a string is just a sequence of `char`s).  Actually representing it as such will not just make this situation easier (and less error-prone), but will pay similar dividends anywhere else you need to use them.

So define some class that encapsulates the datatypes involved, something like:

```
public class MyFoo {
    final int firstNum;
    final String firstDesc;
    final int secondNum;
    final String secondDesc;
    final boolean trueFalseBit;

    // Constructor, equals, hashcode etc. elided
}
```

Then whenever you first get a string like `str1` passed into your system, convert it into an instance of `MyFoo` by tokenising, converting the tokens to ints, etc - whatever is appropriate for the String format.

Now that you have an actual class with different fields of concrete types, you can properly think about sorting by one or more of those fields.  There are then two ways to do this.

Firstly, you could make your class implement `Comparable` and define a `compare` method which will sort in this order.  This only really makes sense if this is a "natural ordering" for your instances; something that makes sense as a default sort in the majority of situations.

Otherwise, you can define your own instance of `Comparator<MyFoo>`, which sorts the objects using whatever order you like.  An example using my class above might be:

```
Comparator<MyFoo> cmp = new Comparator<MyFoo>() {
    public int compare(MyFoo a, MyFoo b) {
       return b.secondNum - a.secondNum;
    }
}
```

### The Hacky Way

Simply write a custom `Comparator<String>` to pull out "the second int" of each string, and sort them accordingly.  This would be similar to the parsing code you would use if you were to convert these strings into a class - perhaps something like:

```
Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
    private int getSecondInt(String s) {
        String[] parts = s.split(" ");
        // TODO check length is at least 3
        return Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        // TODO handle exceptions
    }

    public int compare(String a, String b) {
       return getSecondInt(b) - getSecondInt(a);
    }
}
```

This way might make more sense if you're just using these strings once to sort and then throwing them away - so there's little benefit to building a full object.